# How Duplicate characters of a column into another column in a dataFtrame with R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, for-loop

I have a dataframe with several columns. I want to work on two of the columns by replacing the characters from cell *2-154* of **region** column to duplicate in column **country** also from *2-154*.

I tried to use a *forloop* but i could not  achieve any  result. am relatively new with *R*

The two columns in the  DataFrame  looks like this

| region | country |
| --- | --- |
| Albania | NA |
| Albania | NA |
| united state | NA |
| Germany | na |
| Austria | NA |

This is just a sample of the data. What i want to  achieve  is to duplicate the characters of *region* column into *country* column instead of the **NAs**

I need assistant on how to do this .

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you just need to do `df$country = df$region`. This will just copy the `region` column to `country` column. And `df` is the name of your data frame.

Comment: Hello Antoniosk, Thank your for your response. but I have 4692 rows. I only need the duplication from the second row to row number 154

Comment: Try `df$country[2:154] = df$region[2:154]` but check if you consider the column name as row 1 or not. Because R will ignore the first value if you use `[2:154]`.